# String literal still ending up with double slashes?

Tags: c#, string, string-literals

I have a small piece of code:

```
public static void Write(string filename){
    string time = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm tt");
    int date = int.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd"));
    string path = @"C:\Users\Public\" + filename;
}
```

If I debug and stop just after path is set it looks like `“C:\\\Users\\\Public\\\filename.txt”.`

Can anyone tell me why it has the double slashes? Is the `'@'` sign actually messing it up in this case?

How I may get it as `“C:\Users\Public\filename.txt”`

Comment: If you open your Immediate Window and type `path` and hit Enter, it should display the string properly. It's just displaying like that in the debugger.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The double slashes are only there for the debugger, not your actual application. Your code is fine.

Comment: And the debugger shows the literal as correct C#: just without the @. It would correctly round-trip as shown.

Comment: Boy do I feel silly, the issue was actually during the file write, somebody changed a line of code >_< and I mistook that as the problem.

Comment: The escaped debugger has caught a few people out. When trying to fix a problem, every little thing starts to look suspicious :D