# How to Replace two slashes to one single slashe? C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a problem with somwthing about replace char. I tryied a lot of links but get the same problem to replace (`\\`) to (`\`)

here is my code:

```
 string mystringA = textBox.text
 string mystringB = mystringA.Replace("\\", "\"");
```

The result of mystringB stay the same as mystringA.
I am saying because I put a debug mode to see the result

My textBox.txt = C:\Users\Braulio Jose\Desktop\impressora\myfoto.png

I have to replace the double quotes because I want to delete this photo in another place but when I follow the path, mystringA put another quote, and I this path don't exist

I am using visual studio 2013 and C# Language.
Some help. thank you

Comment: ``\`` is an escape character in C#. The actual contents of `mystringA` is `C:\Users\myname\Desktop\impressora\myFoto.png`, which is almost certainly already what you want with no further replacing necessary. An alternate way of writing this is `@"C:\Users\myname\Desktop\impressora\myFoto.png"`.

Comment: You may want to read something like http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Strings.aspx#literals where it talks about escape sequences. In summary your strings don't contain what you seem to think they do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String literal still ending up with double slashes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14386076/string-literal-still-ending-up-with-double-slashes)

Comment: @Chris I have to replace the double quotes because I want to delete this photo in another place but when I follow the path, mystringA put another quote, and I this path don't exist

Comment: No need to apologise for your english. Its better than my grasp of any foreign languages. :) For your question - it is still unclear to me why you think you need to do this at all. You say the value of your textbox is `C:\Users\Braulio Jose\Desktop\impressora\myfoto.png` whcih doesnt' have any doubles in it. Have you read the comment question that mjwills linked as a duplicate? The chances are your string doesn't have doubled slashes but the way you are viewing it in the debugger makes it seem that way and thus if you are having a problem it probably isn't the one you've described here.

Comment: Please, read the duplicate I suggested. **You do not need the `Replace` call. There are no double slashes.**

Answer (score 0):

Due to the fact, that your question is about quotes, but your code is about slashes, it's hard to guess what your real problem is.

But here is some sample code for both replacements:

```
var replaceQuotes = "Some text with \"\"double quotes\"\"";
var replacedQuotes = replaceQuotes.Replace("\"\"", "\"");
Console.WriteLine("Before: " + replaceQuotes);
Console.WriteLine("After:  " + replacedQuotes);

Console.WriteLine();

var replaceSlashes = "Some text with \\\\double slashes\\\\";
var replacedSlashes = replaceSlashes.Replace("\\\\", "\\");
Console.WriteLine("Before: " + replaceSlashes);
Console.WriteLine("After:  " + replacedSlashes);
```

And here the output:

```
Before: Some text with ""double quotes""
After:  Some text with "double quotes"

Before: Some text with \\double slashes\\
After:  Some text with \double slashes\
```